# servicestack text, json deserialization Index was outside the bounds of the array exception

Tags: servicestack

i was diagnosing an issue where i had json or jsv objects being received in web form or query variables and was getting an Index was outside the bounds of the array exception being thrown by servicestack.  This is a rest client in another product sending this to my servicestack rest services.

I narrowed it down to de-serializing a form variable with an empty string as the value instead of json.

this is a simple test case that does the same thing.  I would have expected null being returned?
v3.9.26 servicestack.text

`

```
    class simpleDTO {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }


    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var json = "";
        var o = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString(json, typeof(simpleDTO));

        Assert.IsNull(o);
    }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That issue was fixed in this commit: [6ea6f235dc](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/c151fae58e927d2aee166dc5192943671ef87644) and should be included in the next ServiceStack.Text release.